# Determine local connectivity in python

Tags: python, sockets

How can I tell if my client system has a network connection using python? I can assume the client connected with DHCP. I can't use lists of known reliable sites to ping to test the connection, as it needs to work in isolated networks as well as open ones.

I thought about fetching the local ip (should work, so long as it doesn't only return loopback). But....

```
print socket.gethostbyaddr('localhost')
```

returns

```
('localhost', ['ip6-localhost', 'ip6-loopback'], ['::1'])
```

which isn't very useful. Any other ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`localhost` should always return `127.0.0.1` in ip4, `'::1'` in ip6, so of course it's not going to be useful -- it's the *loopback* interface, not the ethernet card or whatever;-).

Personally, I'd use `subprocess.Popen` to run `ifconfig` and parse the results (it's spelled `ipconfig` in Windows) -- not ideal, but pretty practical, IMNSHO;-).

Comment: Indeed. I suppose it would be a simple matter to search for 'inet addr:' in the response.

Comment: @direct, unfortunately depends a bit on the platform (e.g., on my Mac ifconfig says `inet 192.168.1.75` and the like, no `addr:` there), but it should be feasible to concoct either a smart-ish RE to match on various platforms, or a platform-dependent simple string check (you need to be a little platform dependent anyway to say `ifconfig` on unix and `ipconfig` on windows, after all).

Comment: use `ip` commands - ifconfig is deprecated. You could also try querying NetworkManager on Linux as a first try, then fall back on parsing the output of `ip addr`.

Comment: thanks mikeyb, I've gone with: while('state UP' in subprocess.Popen(['ip','addr']):